# Best way to achieve multiple part ring in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to dynamically create a view that looks like this[image: this image]

I'm looking for something like a pie chart that shows wins, draws and loses. Also the requirement is to be able to put a drawable(or image) in the center. I tried to adjust ProgressBar and [MP Android chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for those requirements.

With MPAndroidChart there seems to be an issue that the drawable I use in the center is not actually centered and you cannot set the thickness for a certain pie block(or maybe I couldn't find it).

May I ask for a suggestion, what should I use here? Maybe I can draw this programmatically using shapes? Or should I use multiple ProgressBars in a FrameLayout? Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe overlaying multiple progressbars in a framlayout or relativeLayout should do the trick. I think finding a library that does exactly what you want might be tricky, and might include alot of "features" that you don't need that could cause trouble.

programatically drawing it using shapes is certainly possible, but i think it would be way more complicated. I guess in the end it depends on how dynamic it needs to be, and what special functionality you need. using multiple progressbars will probably be the easiest, but will not be as flexible.

Comment: that's the thing, see, they should be created dynamically, basically I have to find the way to rotate second progress bar to match the end of the first progress bar and the same thing with the third one.

Comment: just set the rotation property. if the first part is 25% of the circle that equals 90 degrees, so then you just set android:rotation="90" on the second part

Comment: ok but can I do that programmatically? Unfortunately google gives me results explaining screen rotation xD

Comment: .setRotation((float) 90.0);